# Mirth, Change File Writter Destination after each message

Tags: mirth

Im working with a Mirth Channel.

Source is a Database Reader, Destination currently is a File Writter.

Im attempting to get a xml message from the database, transform it to HL7 and store it on a flat file. Each HL7 message needs to be stored on a separate flat file.

So far mirth gets the xml, transforms it into HL7 but it stores all the messages in the same flat file.

Any tips on what should i try? Should i use JavaScript writter instead of a File Writter?

Comment: Is there an expectation for how the files should be named or do you just need them to be unique?

Comment: @agermano File names does not matter. Mirth creates a total of 10 messages. Each message needs to be stored on a different flat file.

Answer (score 2):

In light of your response that the format of the file name is not important, this is a simple solution. Just drag-and-drop "Message ID" from the destination Mappings box to the File Name box. Every message for this channel will have a unique message id.

Alternatively, you can type `${message.messageId}` into the File Name box.

Answer (score 0):

The file writer destination has two fields to be filled the directory and file name. In this case, I suggest combining string literals with a couple of global or system variables such as count, date, rawdata etc. (check the bottom right pane of the destination transformer for this). In the below example, I am using the count feature to serialize messages that are converted to HL7 in addition to the system date variable which will show the date a message is processed.

[Custom name for file name in the Mirth Connect file writer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqI7t.png)